# How do I revoke a SELECT permission on one column of a table and still allow the user to do a SELECT * FROM the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

From this answer, you can GRANT/REVOKE access to a specific column: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98626/141819

```
GRANT SELECT ON <schema>.<tablename>(<Col1>,<Col2>) TO [Domain\User]
```

However, when I do this it gives the user an error when they try to do a SELECT * that says that they don't have access to the column. Also, it makes Power BI throw an error saying the same thing. Is it possible to revoke access and make it so that when they do SELECT *, it just shows them all the columns that they have access to?

Comment: *"However, when I do this it gives the user an error when they try to do a SELECT \*"* Why wouldn't you expect that error? The user doesn't have access to all the columns, and they are asking for *all the columns*. If you want to return *specific* columns then don't use `*`; you *shouldn't* be using it anyway.

Comment: You can give them a view which only contains the columns they should access and remove access to the actual table

Comment: @ThomA the real end goal is for this to work in Power BI and when you load in data from SQL Server, it seems to be doing its own SELECT *.

Comment: I assume these direct queries then, @TheMortiestMorty, rather than data refreshes, with the data stored in the cloud?

Comment: @siggemannen yea that's plan Z, but I coulda sworn I saw a way to make this work by just revoking access to 1 column about 4 or 5 years ago...

Comment: @ThomA yea direct query

Comment: You could mask/encrypt the data i guess. But don't think it's possible to hide the column altogether

Answer (score 4):

Those two things are mutually exclusive. If a user runs a `SELECT *`, they'll get **all** the columns. Revoking column permissions does *not* magically change the way a query operates, and if the user lacks permission for this the whole query will fail.

Here's the good news: `SELECT *` is poor practice in the first place, and making people choose which columns they need is a good thing to do.

But if you *really* want to do this, you can make a view with the offending column omitted, and allow them to select from the view.

Comment: And yes, I know this answer echoes what's already in the comments, but I swear I wrote this first and read the comments second.